# How to dynamically handle Laravel routes using variable in slug

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to have a route entry that dynamically handles requests based on the slug in the URL. I tried the code below, but the closure seems to be getting in the way. I replaced the closure with controller actions, too, and tried other options without success. The best I came up with thus far is below:

```
$bladeFiles = [
    "about-us",
    "join",
    "contact",
];

foreach ($bladeFiles as $thisView) {
    Route::get($thisView, function () {
        global $thisView;
        if (View::exists($thisView)) {
            return view($thisView);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('homepage');
        }
    })->name($thisView);
}
```

The issue with the above snippet is that `global $thisView` is always null inside the closure.

Thoughts?

Comment: I answered the null thisView issue, but can you maybe tell us what you trying to accomplish by having dynamic routes, as I am sure there should be a better way of handling it than the above. :)

Comment: @emotality I have a vanilla php app that I want to convert to a Laravel app. To hasten things up, I just renamed the individual `sample-file.php` to `sample-file.blade.php` and saved it in the views folder. For the nav menu, I loop through that same `$bladeFiles` array and did `<a href="{{route(...)}}>...`
That's what landed me here. (Apart from feeling too lazy to type all the route for each link - which is a fairly long list, I think I may learn more if handle this dynamically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the `$thisView` through with the `use`:

```
$bladeFiles = [
    "about-us",
    "join",
    "contact",
];

foreach ($bladeFiles as $thisView) {
    Route::get($thisView, function () use ($thisView) { // <-- here
        if (View::exists($thisView)) {
            return view($thisView);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('homepage');
        }
    })->name($thisView);
}
```

Comment: Correction: this works! I wrongly commented above because I already tried this approach. However, the mistake I made was that my closure had a parameter to it, thus causing `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\Router::{closure}` error in my original implementation

Comment: Great news! And you should rewrite your routes ;) hehe

Comment: Yeah man...but maybe that'll be when I'm more hardworking! :s)

Answer (score 0):

Hello i'm doing something very similar to what you want

```
Route::get('pages/{pageName}',function($pageName){
 if(view()->exists('pages.'.$pageName)){
   return view('pages.'.$pageName);
 } else {

  return redirect('/');

 }

});
```

so what i'm doing is i'm having a folder with the name pages 
i write the views into that folder with the slug names like contact-us.blade.php 
when i go to the route "pages/contact-us" it searches for that view in the folder 
if it exists it returns the view else just redirect to the home page 
the only difference in my code that you will have to call the routes like that 
  `{{url('pages/"$pageName"')}} instead of {{rout($pageName)}}`  
i hope my code helps

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as "dynamic" because this is provided out-of-the-box by Laravel (named parameters or so). However, thanks for the insight man!